# Playing multiple videos at a time

Tags: android, video, android-view, android-video-player

I am using following code to run multiple videos at a time.
**UPDATED CODE**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    video1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    video1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getPackageName()+ "/"+R.raw.sample));
    video1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video1.requestFocus();

    video2=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideview);
    video2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getPackageName()+ "/"+R.raw.sample1));
    video2.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video2.requestFocus();

    Thread view1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY);
            video1.start();
        }
    });

    Thread view2=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY);
            video2.start();
        }
    });

    view1.start();
    view2.start();
}
```

And it is giving me error and

```
mediaPlayer error (1, -110)
```

And suddenly dialog box appears and shows that can not play this video

Any suggesion??

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: Why you are creating the videoview object inside a thread and why dont you run both videos on seperate thread??

Comment: I tried that before.. But It was not even playing single video.. So I tried this.. If you can help me out in that way also you are always welcome

Comment: @SiddharthVyas: I have editied my question n uploaded log cat..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do UI related operations on background threads. Android does all UI operations on the main thread. That's why the error message says "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: So can you suggest me any other way??

Comment: You can use post method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: I tried to explore on it.. Can you tell me how to use AsyncTask to the code given by me??

Comment: did you try the code I posted above? Even within a AsyncTask you can't do UI operations in the doInBackground method.

Comment: private class StatusRunner implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<video.length;i++){
 videoviews[i]=(VideoView)findViewById(video[i]);
 videoviews[i].post(new Runnable() {       
  @Override
  public void run(){
   videoviews[i].setMinimumHeight(height);
   videoviews[i].setMinimumWidth(width);
   videoviews[i].setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getPackageName()+ "/"+videofiles[i]));
   videoviews[i].requestFocus();
   videoviews[i].start();        
  }
 });
    }
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions....

Above code posted by me works but it is depend upon h/w accelerator. If it supports multi-`video view` at a time then it will work fine else it will give you error `This media can not be played`